# how use .GetHeadRotation ( As Float)

Tags: basic4android

I use basic4android in Google VR library.

My code is:

```
VrPanoramaView1.GetHeadRotation ( 180,90 As Float)
```

Google documentation says says:

> GetHeadRotation (YawAndPitch() As Float)
>
> Provides yaw and pitch angles corresponding to where the user is
>   looking.
>
> yaw is the rotation along the vertical (y) axis.
>
> Values are in the [-180, 180] range where:
>
> ```
> 0 - looking straight at the initial image orientation.
> 90 - looking 90 degrees to the right.
> -90 - looking 90 degrees to the left.
> -180 or 180 - looking in the direction opposite to the initial one
> ```
>
> pitch is the rotation along the right (x) axis previously rotated by
>   yaw. Values are in the [-90, 90] range where:
>
> ```
> 0 - looking straight, level with the ground.
> 90 - looking up
> -90 - looking down
> ```

Trying to compile produced the following error:

> Error compiling program.
>
> Error description: Cannot cast type: {Type=Double,Rank=0, RemoteObject=False} to: {Type=Float,Rank=1, RemoteObject=True}
>
> Occurred on line: 24 VrPanoramaView1.GetHeadRotation ( 180,90 As
>   Float) Word: 180

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: my error is:Error compiling program.
Error description: Cannot cast type: {Type=Double,Rank=0, RemoteObject=False} to: {Type=Float,Rank=1, RemoteObject=True}
Occurred on line: 24
VrPanoramaView1.GetHeadRotation ( 180,90 As Float)
Word: 180

Comment: I don't know basic4android but it looks like you should try avoid casting that Double to a Float.

Comment: Added a bit of formatting to make it easier to understand.

Comment: i add this: VrPanoramaView1.GetHeadRotation(90x And 90y As Float) and i get this error: input string was not in correct format

Comment: any body can hel me?